# How to robustly detect checkbox value changes in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, checkbox

I'd like to know how to detect changes to an html checkbox input, even when its changed programatically like this:

```
checkboxDomNode.checked = true
```

The browser obviously knows it changed since it gets a visual checkmark, and also any `:checked` css pseudo class gets triggered. I'm actually trying to emulate the `:checked` css pseudo class in javascript, which is why i'm trying to find a robust way to do this.

I've tested the "change" event, and it is not triggered on programatic changes like the above. It also looks like MutationObserver doesn't support changes made to that property.

Answer (score 1):

A small extension to the answer of Alan Darmasaputra: Instead of performing two tasks on each change you can use a simple object wrapper for your checkbox, with a getter and a setter for your property:

```
var checkboxObject = {
    node: document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]'), // or whatever query you wish to perform
    get checked() {
        return this.node.checked;
    },
    set checked(value) {
        var oldValue = this.node.checked;
        this.node.checked = !!value;
        if(oldValue !== !!value) {
            this.node.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
        }
    }
};

checkboxObject.node.addEventListener('change',function(event){
    //do something
});

// calls checkboxObject[get checked]
var state = checkboxObject.checked;

// calls checkboxObject[set checked] with argument 'false'
checkboxObject.checked = false;
```

As you can see, this requires some initial configuration, but then you can both programmatically change the checked state, and dispatch the event in one assignment.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Working fiddle:

```js
var checkboxObject = {
  node: document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]'), // or whatever query you wish to perform
  get checked() {
    return this.node.checked;
  },
  set checked(value) {
    var oldValue = this.node.checked;
    this.node.checked = !!value;
    if(oldValue !== !!value) {
      this.node.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
    }
  }
};

document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkboxObject.checked = true;
});

document.getElementById('uncheck').addEventListener('click', function() {
  checkboxObject.checked = false;
});

checkboxObject.node.addEventListener('change',function(event){
  document.getElementById('log').innerText += 'checkbox value changed! New value: ' + event.target.checked + '\n';
});


// Why implementing this directly on the checkbox element is not a good idea:
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( Object.getPrototypeOf(checkboxObject.node), 'checked' ));
```

```html
<button id="check">check</button>
<button id="uncheck">uncheck</button>

<input type="checkbox">

<div id="log" style="white-space: pre-line"></div>
```

**EDIT: **

Implementing this behaviour directly on the checkbox element is not a good idea. With [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) we can check the type of a property ( an `accessor descriptor`, or a `data descriptor` ). If we do that for the checked property o  the prototype of `checkboxObject.node`, as follows:

`console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( Object.getPrototypeOf(checkboxObject.node), 'checked' ));`

the output will be:

```
{
  "get": function () { [native code] },
  "set": function () { [native code] },
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
}
```

This means that the element already has a getter and setter defined for the property `checked`, in its prototype that is. It IS possible to implement logic where you [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) your checkbox, and call the setter on it explicitly to invoke the native behaviour, but that would make things quite hard to understand real soon, especially because you'd have to bind the context to be your checkbox element for that call. I'll leave it up to you to make a decision about that.

Also keep in mind that an existing (prototype) descriptor might be non-writable (in this case it's not, otherwise it would be in the output above), which means that a normal property assignment for overriding this will fail. In that case you'd have to [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) directly on your checkbox element, to ensure you're not actually trying to override the immutable prototype setters / getters.

Comment: This seems like a good approach if you control all the code. But as soon as you use some external code that might interact with your checkbox, you won't detect a change originating from that code. Perhaps you could modify the dom node object directly?

Comment: Yes that is true. This will of course only work when you are able to tell that code to interact with your wrapper object instead. Of course you would have to extend the wrapper with functionality if chances exist that any external code does not abide your intents with creating this wrapper object. Extending a DOM element directly doesn't seem like a good idea to me, because it might already have a setter of getter with internal procedures. Since it's not (afaik) possible to 'extend' getters and setters, by defining a new setter, all of the native behaviour (if present) would be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try two way binding using any javaScript frameworks like **AngularJS** or **KnockoutJS**. You are also welcome to do it with pure javaScript.

Have a look in this article,

http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/

Simple Example with *AngularJS*

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-controller="checkCtrl">
    Check It : <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" ng-model="checked" />
    <p ng-model="checked">{{checked}}</p>
</div>
```

**AngularJS :**

```
var testApp = angular.module("testApp", []);

testApp.controller("checkCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.checked = true;
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/6KYgX/)

Comment: Do you know how this works in pure javascript? Does it use polling, or does it use some other mechanism? Does it have limitations?

Answer (score 0):

Properties that are programatically modified doesn't fire Events. You could instead try adding onchange listener

```
checkboxDomNode.addEventListener('change',function(event){
 //do something
})
```

and then after modifying your property, fire the event

```
checkboxDomNode.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"))
```

*Tested on Chrome 53*

Comment: If you change the checkbox programmatically, this won't work.